# Creating continuous splines / Making a smooth transition between splines

Tags: algorithm, math, computational-geometry, spline

I'm working on a project that involves creating a spline from a defined set of points (tens of thousands of points).

I first create a spline for the first 1000 points and simulate "driving" on that path with an arrow (it is drawn using the tangent and the current point on spline). When I'm approaching the end of the path I take the next 1000 points and create a new spline and continue my "driving".

The problem that I have is the fact that the splines (previous spline and current spline) don't match at the end. By not matching I mean they don't have the same tangent (first derivative doesn't match) and there is a difference between the last point of the previous spline and first point on the new spline (this is because I'm not using an interpolating spline but a smooth spline - see NOTE1 below). This makes my arrow "jump" at the end of spline, when switching to the newly created spline.

*NOTE1*: I'm **NOT** using interpolating splines. I'm using smooth splines. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Basis-Splines.html) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing_spline) for more details. This means that the set of points given as input may not be on the resulting spline (In my case they are quite close to the spline - but usually **NOT** on the spline).

*NOTE2*: Using an interpolating spline is out of the question because I have a lot of noise in the data used for computing spline.

*NOTE3*: Computing a spline for the entire set of points takes a lot of time (more than 30 seconds) on a 3Ghz PC with 2 GB RAM (our target platform for the application); so doing this is also out of the question.

I'd be interested to overcome that unwanted "jump" when switching splines.

So my questions are:

- Are there some ways/algorithms for doing a smooth "jump"/transition to the new spline?
- Can I do something with a special type of spline to overcome this? (This is what I tried so far without a considerable improvement).

Thank you for any ideas,

Iulian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pretty unsophisticated suggestion, admittedly, but one obvious hack would be to fit overlapping rather than distinct subsets of points and then interpolate between the resulting splines in the overlapping region.

Eg, generate a smooth spline for points 1-1000. While you're animating from 1-900, generate the next spline from 901-1900. For the region between 901 and 1000, use a weighted combination of the corresponding positions in both splines, where the weighting is 1:0 at 901 and 0:1 at 1000. The same for 1801-1900 and so on.

I'd guess that a simple linear interpolation would suffice and the margins probably wouldn't need to be huge, but you could determine that empirically.

Comment: +1 It is an interesting approach; though it is pretty simple, it might prove efficient. I will give it a try. In this case it means that I will end up with two splines until making the "switch" to the next one.

Comment: Since working at math level with spline equations to achieve what I want is probably much difficult, I will probably end up doing this smooth translation from one spline to the other. If no other answers will rise this will probably be the accepted one.

Comment: You could also interpolate control points of the overlapping sections to combine the overlapping splines into one big one, assuming the corresponding parts of the knot vectors line up sensibly.  It isn't the same as pointwise interpolation unless you actually multiply the splines by the transition weight functions (and doing so would result in a higher degree spline anyway, which you probably don't want) but it is fairly close and would probably be worth some experimentation to see whether the result is acceptable.

Comment: (adding to my previous comment) That technique also means you could do a lot more in the precomputation phase because it adds no overhead at runtime.  So, you could probably increase the quality of the fit by using more overlaps; eg, generate splines from points 0-1000, 100-1100, 200-1200, ... and combine ALL of them.  All the extra work is at time of fitting, no extra work at time of evaluation.